# Información del servidor y de ejecución

Tags: aplicación-web

- Estoy trabajando programando en un rotador de sitios webs, pero no estoy muy familiarizado con la cabeceras, rutas y ubicaciones de un servidor web, con el array $_SERVER.
- Para situarnos, tengo el ejemplo siguiente:

http://www.mi_web/rotador/?rot=x

- x es el identificativo del usuario.
- El rotador se compone de web1, web2...
- El usuario utlizara dicho rotador para hacerlo rotar en diferentes fuentes de trafico (o sea en otros sitios webs)

La pregunta es muy precisa...como puedo averiguar la ruta o URL donde utiliza este rotador ??

Estuve probando con

$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

Pero me devuelve el dominio 'http://www.mi_web', NO el dominio que busco, que es donde se ejecuta dicha web.

gracias 
Un saludo

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta: *como puedo averiguar la ruta o URL donde utiliza este rotador*. Da un ejemplo de lo que quieres ...  ¿quieres el valor `x` o qué quieres?, ¿quieres consultar algo en una base de datos?, etc. Gracias.

Comment: NO quiero consultar ninguna base de datos, quiero saber en modo remoto, en que dominio se ejecuta esta web.

Comment: ¿En qué dominio se ejecuta cual web? Sigo sin entender, sería bueno que seas más claro explicando el contexto. De todos modos, haz un `var_dump($_SERVER);` y mira a ver si está ahí el dato que te interesa en alguna de las claves del array (¿`REMOTE_HOST` quizás?) Para que lo puedas ver mejor pon un `echo "<pre>";` antes del var_dump.

Comment: creo que lo explicado claro al principio. pero bueno perdona. Seguro que tiene que ver con $_SERVER, porque recoge datos del server via remoto

Comment: Quizá lo que buscas es **`$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']`** No sé, analiza el `var_dump` y revisa dónde está el valor que buscas.

Comment: Gracias, luego lo hare y dire alguna cosa

Comment: Estuve probando $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] y no funciona. Seguire mirando

Comment: SIgo sin saber la ruta del server remoto desde un sitio web.

Comment: Tengo un rotador web compuesto de un numero de sitios webs, cuyo ejemplo es:

http://www.mi_web/rotador/?rot=x

   -  x es el identificativo del usuario.

   -  El usuario utlizara dicho rotador para hacerlo rotar en diferentes fuentes de trafico (o sea en otros sitios webs).

Comment: Ninguno puede decirme concretamente como puedo saber los dominios donde estan rotando esta URL:          --> mi_web/rotador/?rot=x , Porque esta URL se incluye en varios sitios webs, y quiero saber que dominios son. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hice un 'var_dump' pero no puedo deducir que variable.